# How to save a image from web using its own filename

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

i'm having a array of web urls redirecting images. Is it possible to download images directly and save it using its default file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webImageURL]];
[data writeToURL:localURL atomically:YES];
```

Comment: if the url is http:rockers.net/apple.jpeg, then save it as apple.jpeg

Comment: how to get file name from web url

Comment: use lastPathComponent method of NSURL. [webImageURL lastPathComponent];